# xcodebuild archiving issue

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, xcodebuild

I'm having an issue with xcodebuild. I use the xcodebuild archive command from a build server to create an archive. At the moment, it seems that it will not respect the build configuration I have set. Has anyone come across this, or have any idea how to alter it?

To give a bit more background, within the project I have my build location set as Legacy so that I can build multiple libraries into a single iOS app (similar to how three20 do it), and so I have my build directories set within an xcconfig file as so:

```
BUILD_DIR = ../Build
SYMROOT = ${BUILD_DIR}/Products
OBJROOT = ${BUILD_DIR}/Intermediates
TEMP_ROOT = ${BUILD_DIR}/Temp
```

If I run

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${WORKSPACE} -scheme ${SCHEME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk ${SDK}
```

It all works swimmingly, and the compilation command I get compiles into the common ../Build folder as you can see in the sample output here:

```
CompileC ../Build/Intermediates/Core.build/Release-iphoneos/Core.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/NumberUtils.o Source/NumberUtils.m normal armv7s objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

However if I add archive on the end, and run:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${WORKSPACE} -scheme ${SCHEME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk ${SDK} archive
```

It ignores my build settings, and just uses the DerivedData location:

```
CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/workspace-bmancqbwwpbxuzbdtxezsoptpyur/ArchiveIntermediates/Release/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Core.build/Release-iphoneos/Core.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NumberUtils.o Source/NumberUtils.m
```

Is there something else I need to set? I've set all the environment variables I can think of. Strangely archiving from within xcode itself also works fine. Any advice?